# Three20 json response storing into shared object accessible to multiple views

Tags: objective-c, xcode, json, ios5, three20

I am new to iPhone development and Three20 framework. I created a simple login controller which returns user details as json response from PHP. i need to store json response into an object or something which can be shared on other views, for example i want to show received user details on profile view controller.

```
- (void)requestDidFinishLoad:(TTURLRequest *)request {
_loading = NO;
_loaded = YES;

TTURLDataResponse *response = request.response;

NSString *responseBody = [[NSString alloc]initWithData:response.data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

SBJSON *jsonParser = [[[SBJSON alloc] init] autorelease];

loggedUser = (NSDictionary *) [jsonParser objectWithString:responseBody error:nil];
NSLog(@"%@",loggedUser);

[super requestDidFinishLoad:request]; 

}
```

Rightnow loggedUser is a NSDictionary. I want to access loggedUser in profileViewController.m

please guide. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should move in the direction of creating a Model four your app.

One easy way for that is having your Model as a singleton class that you can the access from everywhere in your code.

Have a look at [this S.O. thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/145154/what-does-your-objective-c-singleton-look-like) for a couple of variant implementations.